# how to set mongo db date format while storing data from date object

Tags: mongodb, gson, date-formatting, bson

I am trying to store POJO in mongo db, having currentDate field. currentDate field is in date type. 
date currentDate= new Date();
it stores date in "MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a" this format in mongo.
how to change this format? I need to add nanoseconds too.

Comment: BSON Dates don't have nanoseconds and are in fact stored as milliseconds since epoch internally so that actually are NOT a "string" and if you have things that look like a string, then they are not BSON Dates. If you want "nanoseconds" for precision then you need to store as a numeric value and ideally separately to the main date field, else you run into very large numbers with a chance of overrunning the maximum 64-bit integer space. Or even the decimal-128 for that matter.

Comment: Ticket if you want to look https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1460 Note that it's 8 years old, so hardly on the high priority list.

Comment: Thanks Neil. if we leave about nanoseconds, How to change default date format in mongo db? As I am not having String type field in pojo, I cant change date format. Is it default date format of Mongo/BSON ("MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a")  for date type Column ? I am beginner in for mondoDb. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you abel to use `DateTime`, too? `DateTime.Ticks`' show you the resolution in 100 nanoseconds.

I had smimilar problems in the past trying to set correct Dates in MongoDB, while saving them directly. I suggest you to create your `own DateTime object` and save it in the MongoDB?

For example like a *SpecifiqueDate*

```
>  public class SpecifiqueDate
>     {
>         public int Year;
>         public int Month;
>         public int Day;
>         public int Houres;
>         public int Minutes;
>         public int Seconds;
>         public long Milliseconds;
>         public long Nanoseconds;
> 
>         public Date(int year, int month, int day, int houres, int minutes, int seconds, long milliseconds, long nanoseconds)
>         {
>             Year = year;
>             Month = month;
>             Day = day;
>             Houres = houres;
>             Minutes = minutes;
>             Seconds = seconds;
>             Milliseconds = milliseconds;
>             Nanoseconds = nanoseconds;
>         } }
```